# Most frequent element stream

Tags: java, java-stream, frequency

How to find most frequent element, but when there are few most frequent element return null.

I would like to find code equivalent of:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Should return A -> " + mostFrequent(Arrays.asList("A", "A", "B")));
    System.out.println("Should null as element in list have same frequency -> "
            + mostFrequent(Arrays.asList("A", "B")));
}

private static String mostFrequent(List<String> elements) {
    Map<String, Long> ordered = new TreeMap<>();
    for (String e : elements) {
        if (!ordered.containsKey(e)) {
            ordered.put(e, 0L);
        }
        Long tmp = ordered.get(e);
        ordered.put(e, ++tmp);
    }

    String mostFrequent = null;
    long i = 0;
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Long>> it = ordered.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext() && i < 2) {
        Map.Entry<String, Long> pair = it.next();
        if (i == 0) {
            mostFrequent = pair.getKey();
        } else {
            if (ordered.get(mostFrequent) == ordered.get(pair.getKey())) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    return mostFrequent;
}
```

However stream version does not handle most frequent elements with the same frequency.

```
private static String mostFrequentStream(List<String> elements) {
    return elements.stream()
            .reduce(BinaryOperator.maxBy(
                    Comparator.comparingInt(o -> Collections.frequency(elements, o))))
            .orElse(null);
}
```

How to modify stream above to achieve it?

Comment: What should be the output of your code for an input `Arrays.asList("A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "C", "B", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E")`? and why is that so? Please specify/update that in the question as well. Its really unclear on to this part, that if *any* two items frequency is same, the most frequent would be returned as `null`.

Comment: @nullpointer the output for `Arrays.asList("A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "C", "B", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E")` should be `null` (you can prove this by running OPs code with the aforementioned list as the input) why is that? because the question that is asked is simply "can I convert my imperative approach to the functional equivalent" whether "null" is a meaningful value to return in the case of there being at least two numbers that have the same amount of occurrences is a different matter.

Comment: @Aomine I am wondering why such an implementation would even exist.. not questioning the solution provided by you, hence the comment here.

Comment: @nullpointer I wasn't referring to my answer directly or indirectly, I was just answering some of the questions you were after. it seems like I wasn't able to answer them for you. I guess it should be interesting to see what the OP says.

Comment: This code is simplification of some business requirements, when you can not return most common element, when there exist other element of same frequency. Hence I return null, but it is just information that such case happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using groupingBy:

```
String mostFrequentStream(List<String> elements) {
    Map<String, Long> temp = elements.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a, Collectors.counting()));


    return new HashSet<>(temp.values()).size() < temp.size() ? 
          null : temp.entrySet()
                     .stream()
                     .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                     .map(Map.Entry::getKey).get();

}
```

Comment: No, I need to return null for second list, cause you have "A" and "B" have same frequency, but code at the top return null.

Comment: I'm not sure if ireturns for every input the right result. Example: `Arrays.asList("A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "C", "B", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E")` -  It returns `null`. The code from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53597196) returns `E`. `E` has a frequency of `4` and there is no other `String` with this frequency. Do I miss something?

Comment: @LuCio no, it should return null if there is at least 2 elements that occur the same number of times as far as my understanding goes...

Comment: Then your code returns the right result. I understood OP looks for one and only one maximum.

Comment: I second the thought from @LuCio here. Nevertheless, the expectation that if any two characters have same frequency null shall be returned looks weird.

Comment: @Aomine You're technically right. Your answer meets this condition. I was guided by the statement: "when there are few most frequent element return null" - As for me OP's question is not clear enough.

Comment: But why are you doing `elements.stream().map(temp::get)` instead of just `temp.values().stream()`? Since duplicates are expected in `elements`, you’re doing duplicate work. I’d even consider not to use a Stream here, e.g. test for `new HashSet<>(temp.values()).size() < temp.size()` instead.

Comment: @Holger good shout as always! and to be honest I didn't really have time to put too much thought into it. I was thinking about coming back to this answer later on to find ways to improve it as I knew it wasn't the best it could be but I've been getting comments everywhere on my answers so didn't have much time. edited and thanks

Answer (score 2):

I managed to build a concatenated `Stream` but it got long:

```
private static String mostFrequentStream3(List<String> elements) {
    return elements.stream() // part 1
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream() // part 2
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue))
            .entrySet().stream() // part 3
            .max(Entry.comparingByKey())
            .map(Entry::getValue)
            .filter(v -> v.size() == 1)
            .map(v -> v.get(0).getKey())
            .orElse(null);
}
```

To "find most frequent element, but when there are few most frequent element return null"
Part 1 counts the frequency of every element.
Part 2 groups entries by frequency.
Part 3 looks up the entry with the highest frequency. If this entry does only have one element ("there are few most frequent"), then it's the one and only maximum. Otherwise `null` is returned.

Answer (score -1):

I would never use stream for this to avoid hurting readability and performance at the same time. For the sake of fun -

```
private static String mostFrequentStream(List<String> elements) {
    Map<String, Long> frequencyMap = elements.stream().collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));

    return frequencyMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
            .limit(2).reduce((i, e) -> i.getValue().equals(e.getValue()) ? new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(null, 0L) : i).get().getKey();
}
```